# How do build and release with outed packages in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app I just cloned from GitHub and some of the flutter packages are outed and so some of the classes are deprecated.
That is when I upgrade the packages I get deprecation error.
I just want to know Can you build and release your app even though packages are outed in flutter ?
so that I don't have to upgrade the packages and just continue with the outed once.

Answer (score 0):

Outdated packages versions must work alongside with old flutter versions if you do not want to encounter some `deprecation` errors. Instead, you can simply upgrade the packages

Comment: Cool thanks for the response, If I understand you correctly your saying if I downgrade my flutter version  to the projects flutter version, i can build a release apk without any issues or deprecation warning?